# Config QtCreator project with distant build directory

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to automatically configure QtCreator with a build directory that is in a distant part of the file system tree?

If my sources are in:-

```
/home/pete/repository/sources/path/app/main.cpp
etc
```

my projects in:-

```
/home/pete/repository/projects/path/app/app.pro
etc
```

and I want the build in (to keep the bins out of the repository):-

```
/home/pete/builds/keepthesamelevel/path/app/app(.exe)
```

Can I automatically configure the build path to accommodate?

From what I can see `/home/pete/repository/projects/path` are fixed.
I can only automatically configure the app part using the
`%{CurrentBuild:Name}` etc. macros.

At the moment I'm editing the path QtCreator gives me for each
app which is time consuming and error prone.

Comment: I think you can, just write the necessary stuff in the project file (.pro for *qmake*). However, I would advice against messing with this kind of stuff in your project. Life is just easier when you don't have to manage this manually, and instead use the build system defaults. But if you gotta do it, you gotta do it, in which case start by reading through *qmake* manual (or *cmake* if you prefer). Get it to work from command line first, without Qt Creator.

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically'? You can configure QtCreator to build to anywhere you want.

Comment: @jaa-c So when I write a new .pro file and first run qtcreator it configures the build directories as required above without having to edit the paths by hand (as I said in the last sentence).

Comment: I have experienced issues when configuring build path with such distant node ... even Qt recommends the build path to be at same node as source path. even though it might work fine most of the time!